# Errors on populating dates from string concatenations in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I have a statement:

`SELECT ('"' || TO_DATE(substr(idate,7,4) || '/' || substr(idate,3,2) || '/' || substr(idate,5,2), 'YYYY/MM/DD') || '"') 
FROM heal;`

which outputs 

`"15/02/04"
"15/01/03"
"15/01/20"
"15/01/10"`

But I've created a column from this query to populate it as a DATE (`ALTER TABLE heal ADD (CDATE DATE);`)

While inserting 

`INSERT INTO heal (cdate) VALUES 
    ('"' || TO_DATE(substr(idate,7,4) || '/' || substr(idate,3,2) || '/' || substr(idate,5,2), 'YYYY/MM/DD') || '"');`

I get Error: `00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"`

When leaving outside quotes I have the same. This is something with quotes I've read in many other duplicated threads but still don't know how to quote it. Any he;p?

'idate' column as VARCHAR2(50):

`b'02042015'
b'01032015'
b'01202015'
b'01102015'`

Comment: May we ask why you are storing date information as text?

Comment: I said without quotes it's the same.

Comment: Please add sample data for the `idate` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rather want an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`.

```
UPDATE heal
       SET cdate = to_date(substr(idate, 7, 4) || '/' || substr(idate, 3, 2) || '/' || substr(idate, 5, 2), 'YYYY/MM/DD');
```

Comment: Oh dear, UPDATE worked. But why can't insert? Is this some violation ?

Comment: @Peter.k: `INSERT` inserts new rows, not values in empty columns.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you need to make things so complicated:

```
UPDATE heal
SET cdate = TO_DATE(SUBSTR(idate, 3, 8), 'DDMMYYYY');
```

You don't need to use all that string manipulation.  Just call `TO_DATE` once with the proper format mask.

Comment: True, but I've got some error earlier because MM was before DD and made such concatenation without proper reason.

Comment: Apparently the OP's string values are not eight digit strings; in addition to that, the strings are enclosed in single quotes (as part of the strings!) and with a leading lower-case b. As in, `b'01202015'`. So you need to apply `TO_DATE` to `SUBSTR(idate, 3, 8)`. Or apply a format model with boilerplate text.

Comment: @mathguy I didn't know if those single quotes were literal values, thanks for commenting.

Comment: What I said seems to match the OP's attempt: look where he is extracting the substrings from. Starting at positions 3, 5 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this. I show a full demo, beginning with the creation of the table, populating the data (with `NULL` in the `CDATE` column), then the `UPDATE` statement. Note the use of "boilerplate text" in the format model to `TO_DATE`, and the use of q-quoting syntax to define strings that include single-quotes as literal characters.

In the final output, `CDATE` uses my current session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter; the dates may look different on your system.

```
create table heal (idate varchar2(50), cdate date);

insert into heal (idate)
  select q'[b'02042015']' from dual union all
  select q'[b'01032015']' from dual union all
  select q'[b'01202015']' from dual union all
  select q'[b'01102015']' from dual;

select * from heal;

IDATE                          CDATE                     
------------------------------ --------------------------
b'02042015'                                                                  
b'01032015'                                                                  
b'01202015'                                                                  
b'01102015'

update heal
  set cdate = to_date(idate, q'["b'"mmddyyyy"'"]');


4 rows updated.

select * from heal;

IDATE                          CDATE              
------------------------------ -------------------
b'02042015'                    2015/02/04 00:00:00
b'01032015'                    2015/01/03 00:00:00
b'01202015'                    2015/01/20 00:00:00
b'01102015'                    2015/01/10 00:00:00
```